# How do I sum the last 10 rows of column "D". with the result in a cell in column "F"?

Tags: google-sheets

I have been using this and it works, but everyday I add a new row and have to insert a row above this formula, that's why I want it to display in column "F" somewhere:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-10,COLUMN(),4) &":"& ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN(),4)))
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2):

You can try `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A:A)<=COUNTA(A:A))*(ROW(A:A)>COUNTA(A:A)-10)*A:A)
```

There can't be blanks in `A:A`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your range of values in D:D is contiguous (i.e., no blanks) and begins at the top of the column (with or without a header), you can use this:

`=ArrayFormula(SUMIF(ROW(D:D),">"&COUNTA(D:D)-10,D:D))`

If there are interspersed blanks in the range, you can use either of these:

`=SUM(SORTN(FILTER(D:D,ISNUMBER(D:D)),10,0,FILTER(ROW(D:D),ISNUMBER(D:D)),0))`

`=SUM(QUERY(FILTER({D:D,ROW(D:D)},ISNUMBER(D:D)),"Select Col1 ORDER BY Col2 DESC LIMIT 10"))`

Comment: Hm, the last two formulas will give a different result from the original OP formula if there are empty cells in the last ten rows because they will be ignored and the last ten numbers will be counted.

Comment: Since we don't know the data or the actual end goal, yes: I assumed the OP would want a sum of actual numbers. Without more information than was provided, who can know?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=SUM(QUERY(SORT(D2:D; ROW(D2:D); ); 
 "where Col1 is not null limit 10"; ))
```